# vim in tmux lose highlighting

Tags: syntax-highlighting, tmux

I'm using vim 8.0 and tmux 2.5 on ubuntu.

And I have set the TERM environment `export TERM=screen-256color` and run as `tmux -2`.

Normally, nothing goes wrong. It's like the following picture:

[image: Normal]

But after I move cursor over the right parenthesis several times,
the highlighting will be lost, like the following picture:

[image: lost]

If I run the commands `:NoMatchParen` in vim,
nothing goes wrong.

Is there any solution to it without turning off parenthesis matching?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps downgrading tmux would help? I use vim 8.0 with tmux 1.9a, which is my favorite version. Latest tmux seem to introduce minor issues.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I still prefer to the newest version of tmux. Maybe I should disable the parenthesis matching.

Comment: Not an answer, but I've noticed artifacts like this with italics toggling on/off as I move the cursor over italicized highlights. It only happen inside tmux. Commenting to reinforce that I believe this is a tmux bug and not anything in your personal Vim config.

Comment: @JimStewart Thanks. Hope the bug will be fixed.